# Add gategory description - cant find the category page parent file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have found the function which outputs the category description:

```
function category_description( $category = 0 )
```

Now i need to locate the page, where all categoryes are populated, but it seems that I'm not able to find it (its not archives.php).

[This](http://themethesis.com/tutorials/show-category-descriptions/) tutorial states that archives.php is the correct file, but it seems like there has been some structure changed recently. Category.php is only the function holder, not populater.

Wordpress 3.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, it was just badly/non-conventionally built theme called [LightWood](http://www.lightword-theme.com/) and all the switching (pages, categoryes, archives) was done in index.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you're looking for but category_description() calls `function &get_term` in the file taxonomy.php